# Gas fireplace works if I tap on it

Tags: gas, fireplace

I have an Arrow DM10 stand-alone gas fireplace that was built in 1993. It has a working pilot and a new thermopile. It will not light on its own.

After replacing the thermopile with no result, I poked about on Google and found someone that said I should tap the gas manifold. I did and it started right up.

Unfortunately it didn't say WHY this might work. Anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: It sounds like the gas valve's moving bits are getting stuck?

Comment: That's what I think, but how to test that theory?

Comment: Maybe put a gas "sniffer" probe near the orifice furthest from the pilot and pull it away as soon as the flames start to propagate towards it?